# View TouchDB mobile database in desktop

Tags: rest, couchdb, couchdb-futon, touchdb

I launch TouchDB database from my iOS application. It works as http server via TouchDB framework class - TDListener and it provide REST API for external access.
How can I view database from my desktop?
Are there some frontend applications which can be adopted for viewing my mobile database? 
I've considered couchdb-futon but I don't know how tune it for my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options mentioned here:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Tools-for-TouchDB

Your best best is probably TouchDB Viewer:

"TouchDB Viewer — "Official" GUI app for viewing TouchDB databases. Runs on Mac OS. Can view local database files (including ones in the iOS Simulator) or remote ones given their URL (useful if you enable the listener in your iOS app.)"
-- https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDBViewer

I'm sure you could get futon talking to TouchDB, but it'd probably involve delving into the futon codebase.

**EDIT:**
TouchDB is the legacy 1.0 version of the project now named [Couchbase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios). So, the "TouchDB Viewer" has been [converted to support Couchbase Lite](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer/commit/c847775200eacb36d61497328a5f6188e8587865) databases (which has '.cblite' extension) and also it has been renamed to "[CouchbaseLiteViewer](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer) - Mac app for viewing/modifying Couchbase Lite databases".